# Anyone know a common-words list for IT terminology?

Tags: dictionary, tags, tag-cloud

I need them for help in building a tag cloud which needs to include IT terms like java, testing, versioning, patterns, agile etc etc.

Need a few hundred words at least.

Comment: Isn't a tag cloud usually built from an existing corpus of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Top 200 tags in StackOverflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6784/top-tags-based-on-question-count) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps "borrow" the stackoverflow tag list? click on the "tags" tab at the top and you can page through their tags.

Answer (score 1):

The "Glossary of Java and Related Terms" gives you quite a number of terms:
http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/book/glossary.html

(Originally http://java.sun.com/docs/glossary.html was provided, too, in this answer, but the link is dead now).

Comment: In this case, a link is fine. Adding the 100s of terms in the answer itself is a bit overkill. (I *did* edit the question as the the Sun java link has gone 404 now).